# Trying to find minimal value with CTE

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, common-table-expression

I need find cheapest value and then retrieve information about this value. I'm trying to get this by using CTE for retrieve chepest item and then INNER JOIN for retrieve item information, but I'm getting 3 records instead of single record. How may I get single records?

```
  ;WITH GroupedData AS (
SELECT c.SparePartId, MIN(c.Price) AS MinPrice FROM Catalogue c
    WHERE c.SparePartId  = @SparePartId
    GROUP BY c.SparePartId
    )
  SELECT DISTINCT sp.Id, gd.MinPrice, sp.Name, Image
  FROM SpareParts sp
  INNER JOIN Photos p ON sp.Id = p.SparePartId
  INNER JOIN GroupedData gd ON sp.Id = gd.SparePartId
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you have three `Photos` for that `SpareParts.Id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your group by and your WHERE in your CTE demands that the result be a single record:

```
SELECT c.SparePartId, MIN(c.Price) AS MinPrice FROM Catalogue c
WHERE c.SparePartId  = @SparePartId
GROUP BY c.SparePartId
```

And since it's unlikely that you have multiple records for each `sparepart` in your `spareparts` table. Then the INNER JOIN to `photos` must be causing the inflation of records, which means that for your `@SparePArtID` you must have three `Photos` records.